# How can I upload media using go-twitter bot?

Tags: go, twitter

I'm new to go, and have made this simple bot using `go-twitter` package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter"
    "github.com/dghubble/oauth1"
)

func main() {
    consumerKey := "SECRET"
    consumerSecret := "SECRET"
    accessToken := "SECRET"
    accessSecret := "SECRET"

    config := oauth1.NewConfig(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
    token := oauth1.NewToken(accessToken, accessSecret)

    // OAuth1 http.Client will automatically authorize Requests
    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

    // Twitter client
    client := twitter.NewClient(httpClient)

    tweet, resp, err := client.Statuses.Update("Hi baby, I'm just a bot!", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("TWEETED: %+v , %v\n", tweet.Text, resp)
}
```

I'm wondering how can I upload media using this bot?

I see there is a `MediaIds` in [the source code](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/master/twitter/statuses.go#L168), but have not clue how to use that and there is no explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such [functionality](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/issues/76).

Comment: So what are the MediaIds in the struct for?

Comment: If you have ids of the medias you able to use it.

Comment: How? Can you give an example please?

Comment: Also you can use https://github.com/twitter/twurl in order to upload media and get an id. Here is an example of struct with media `StatusUpdateParams{MediaIds: []int64{123456789, 987654321}`

Comment: Not sure `twurl` would be useful for my use case, as it `... will return an URL that you should open up in your browser.` . The bot has no browser.

Comment: Read at the bottom of page https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices